# Why isn't this `expr ... | bc -l` command working?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, bc

I'm noticing an error:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `-105.5*7+50*3'

When executing the below script/expression:

```
expr (-105.5*7+50*3)/20 + (19^2)/7 | bc -l
```

Is there any other way to evaluate such mathematical/floating point operations?

#### EDIT #1

**NOTE:** `echo` in place of `expr` does resolve this however I've used `expr` with `bc` before and it has handled floats quite normally why not in this scenario is what I'd like to find out now.

Comment: Replace `expr` with `echo` and put quotes around the expression.

Comment: [sonu@localhost ~]$ echo (-105.5*7+50*3)/20 + (19^2)/7 | bc -l
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `-105.5*7+50*3'

Comment: @user2546040 You replaced `expr` with `echo`, but you forgot the second part. Quote the expression.

Comment: thanks  @wurtel is there any specific reason we need to use echo instead of expr because echo seems to have solve the expression

Comment: `expr` is a command that can also perform (basic integer) arithmetic, but then it's pointless to pipe its output to `bc -l` which also does mathematics. Choose one or the other, not both. Using `echo` sends the expression to the standard input of `bc -l` which then evaluates the expression.

Comment: @user2546040 - you cannot use `expr` in this scenario b/c the expressions involves floats. `expr` can only deal with integer or strings.

Comment: @slm well yes i would definitely would like to know why expr was not able to handle floats in this scenario with bc however expr did work out for below                       [sonu@localhost ~]$ expr 3.124*1.35 | bc
4.217

Comment: You are getting that error because bash dosent have the capability of doing floating point arithmetic. You can used `bc -l  <<< "(-105.5*7+50*3)/20 + (19^2)/7 "` that would be simple.

Comment: @user2546040 - the `expr` command just doesn't handle floats. It states this in the man page for it. It's just a limitation of that particular command, and is usually why you don't see it used all too often.

Comment: `expr` also doesn't handle exponents (the `19^2` part).

Comment: @wrutel & slm thank you both I always thought piping with bc provided expr with that functionality now i am convinced thank you all for your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that earlier you placed quotes around `expr` parameters, like this:

```
$ expr '(-105.5*7+50*3)/20 + (19^2)/7' | bc -l
22.14642857142857142857
```

?

In this case `expr` doesn't perform any arithmetic operations and just prints the original expression:

```
$ expr '(-105.5*7+50*3)/20 + (19^2)/7'        
(-105.5*7+50*3)/20 + (19^2)/7
```

All calculations happen in the `bc -l`, and the whole command gives the right answer (although `expr` actually works as `echo`).